# Next.js & MongoDB (without Mongoose) returning empty array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, next.js

I'm using API routes in Next.js with sample data from MongoDB. I am trying to return the data from a single object. First time working with MongoDB, so apologies if the answer has been staring me in the face.

I'm getting an empty array returned with the following query:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from '../../../util/mongodb';

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();

  const movies = await db
    .collection("movies")
    .find({ "_id": "573a1395f29313caabce1f51" })
    .limit(20)
    .toArray();

  res.json(movies);
};
```

Which corresponds to an object like this:

```
{
"_id": "573a1395f29313caabce1f51",
"fullplot": "some text goes here"
}
```

What am I missing? Shouldn't `.find({_id: "573a1395f29313caabce1f51"})` return that information? Why am I only seeing an empty array? I understand why it's returning an array (I added `.toArray()`), but that shouldn't impact whether the results are returned or not.

For what it's worth, querying without parameters works properly. No issues with this query:

```
import { connectToDatabase } from '../../util/mongodb';

export default async (req, res) => {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();


  const movies = await db
    .collection("movies")
    .find({})
    .sort({ metacritic: -1 })
    .limit(20)
    .toArray();

  res.json(movies);
};
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you use any ODM like [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com)?

Comment: If you don't use mongoose then you need to cast `573a1395f29313caabce1f51` to ObjectID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to cast to an objectID as mentioned in the comments.

- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/